# Can/should directories for test frameworks be consolidated into a top-level directory (a la vendor/plugins)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, code-organization

For some reason, I find it really irksome that the files for each testing framework (rspec, test::unit, cucumber, etc.) live in a separate folder in the top level of my app.  Is there a strong reason these directories should be scattered about instead of consolidated like gems/plugins in the vendor directory?

If there isn't an actual reason for the way it is, would it be kosher to consolidate these directories into a top-level "test" directory, containing subdirectories for each of the testing frameworks alongside fixture data, etc.?  Has anyone else ever been driven bonkers this (and maybe already hacked together a quick'n'easy way of updating the necessary paths to get this to work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I for one would welcome this change.

Personally I use RSpec and Cucumber at the same time and I'm torn whether or not to put the fixtures in the *features/support/fixtures* directory (I create it myself) or *spec/fixtures*. What if I use this fixture in features and in spec tests too?! [overly emotional] *Why won't somebody think of the fixtures!!*

Definitely. A top-level test directory with the subdirectories of *features*, *specs*, *fixtures* and whatever else you need.

Great question!